# NumberOfItemsInSection is called before CellForItemAt

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I use custom UICollectionView with custom UICollectionViewCell:

```
class SelectTimeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, SliderDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewSlider: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        

        collectionViewSlider?.register(DayCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        collectionViewSlider.dataSource = self
        collectionViewSlider.delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print("*\(indexPath.row)")
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DayCollectionViewCell        
        cell.tag = indexPath.row        
        return cell
    }
}

class DayCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupDayTimeline(width: frame.width, height: frame.height)        
}

func setupDayTimeline(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
    let appsCollectionView: UICollectionView = {            
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: width, height: height - 30), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        return collectionView
    }()

    addSubview(appsCollectionView)
    appsCollectionView.delegate = self
    appsCollectionView.dataSource = self
    appsCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "TimeCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "timecell")
}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(self.tag)
        return myArray[self.tag].count
    }
}
```

But when I scroll my UICollectionView and I get in console:
*0
0
0
*1
1
0
*2

So, for the last cell the function **numberOfItemsInSection** from DayCollectionViewCell is called early then **cellForItemAt** from MyViewController. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's not really clear what your problem is exactly. Also, why does your cell class also implement `UICollectionViewDataSource`?

Comment: I just updated my code. The problem: "cell.tag = indexPath.row" is called later then "return myArray[self.tag].count" and self.tag is 0

Comment: You are probably using the collection view completely wrong. The `cellForItem` will be called always after `numberOfItemsInSection` because the latter is giving the number of items for which `cellForItem` is to be called. PS: *don't use tags.*

Comment: How can I detect current day at DayCollectionViewCell? I need return count of timelines for current day at numberOfItemsInSection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `DayViewCollectionCell` contains another collection view, where the cell is set as its collection view's data source & delegate. Since that's configured in the xib, it immediately starts getting queries from the collection view before you can set the tag.

I think the solution is to not set the data source in the xib, and then set it at runtime after setting the cell's tag. Or, leave it set, and add a `didSet` handler to `cell.tag` where you call `reloadData()` on the cell's collection view.

Comment: Nested collection views are a wrong thing to do in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps one or both should be a stack view instead.